# Regexp struggling

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a string (length =4) with lower case letters and digits. That could be 4 digits but not 4 letters. For example I want to match:

```
d4rt
df5h
34d6
4567
```

But not 'erty'.

I get that pattern `([a-z]+|[0-9]+){4}` but that keeps me the 4 letters case.

Comment: what is the language?

Answer (score 3):

Your regex `([a-z]+|[0-9]+){4}` uses an alternation which will either match 1+ lowercase characters or 1+ digits in a capturing group and repeat that 4 times. That would also match 4 letters.

If [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are supported, you could use a negative lookahead to assert that what follows are not 4 lowercase characters.

To match a string with length of 4,  you could use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string.

`^(?![a-z]{4})[a-z0-9]{4}$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T157SS/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is matching four `{4}` of whatever either any number greater than 1 of lower case letters `[a-z]` or any number greater than one of digits. Therefore, your code is actually matching more than 4 of letters or digits too.

Your problem can be solved with **lookaheads**.

```
(?=[a-z]{0,3}[0-9])[a-z0-9]{4}
```

**(?=[a-z]*[0-9])** looks ahead to find zero or more letters until it finds a number. But when it finds, such a sequence it will continue matching from the beginning of the lookahead. Thin of it as a sort of "pre match".

**[a-z0-9]{4}** This part checks for four numbers or lower case characters, but we are already sure that there is at least one number there because of the lookahead.

Comment: In case the string is more than four characters, e.g. `erty7`, your lookahead should look for 0-3 lower-case only, e.g., `(?=[a-z]{0,3}[0-9])`.

Comment: Yup. Thanks for that! I fixed it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement says, the string should contain at least one digit and rest can be anything containing digits and lowercase alphabets of exactly 4 characters, you can use this regex,

```
^(?=.*\d)[a-z0-9]{4}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` --> Start of input
- `(?=.*\d)` --> Look ahead to ensure the input contains at least one digit
- `[a-z0-9]{4}` --> Ensures only lowercase alphabets and digits are matched in allowed character set
- `$` --> End of input

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2a4U7x/1)